# Parsing and Displaying the values from JSON response into HTML

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation, openstreetmap, nominatim

I am trying to find out current city based on the coordinates obtained from Geolocation API of HTML. Here I have hardcoded the coordinates however I am unable to parse and obtain current city.

The API I am using for obtaining the city name is Nominatim.
I am not sure where I am going wrong with the code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <!--<div><button name="locationdiv" onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button> </div>-->
    <div><button name="citydiv" onclick="getCity()">Current City</button> </div>
</body>    
<script>


    function getCity(){

        const url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=12.93&lon=80.17&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.responseType = 'json';
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send();
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        var newElement2  = document.createElement("div");
        newElement2.innerHTML = Http.responseJSON.address.country;
        document.body.appendChild(newElement2);}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem not to be familiar with the asynchronous nature of a AJAX call.
You cannot just post a AJAX call and then expect the `XMLHttpRequest` object to have it all. You need to define a callback function for the event `onreadystatechange` in which all the action should take place.

```js
const url =
  "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=12.93&lon=80.17&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.responseType = "json";
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var jsonResponse = this.response;
    var newElement2 = document.createElement("div");
    newElement2.innerHTML = jsonResponse.address.country;
    document.body.appendChild(newElement2);
  }
}
```

BTW: There are more modern approaches to *'AJAX'* calls then old XMLHttpRequest, namely `fetch()`

Comment: The snippet is working here if I click on 'Run code snippet' however if I copy this in my code and run it, it doesnt give me anything. I have put an 'else' condition too, still the new element is not appending.

Comment: I removed the `function getCity(){` just for demonstration purposes. I think you still need it.

Comment: And take a look at the missing curly brace (`}`) at the end of the last line. This was the closing bracket for the function and should go on a new line on its own.

Comment: It was the missing the curly brace at the end of the function.
Yes as I started coding this I realised there is another function called fetch() which I will use in further on and Thank you so much.

Comment: You should take more care of your code layout. Having a closing bracket of a function at the end of the line is no good code style.

Comment: Aye I will. Thank you.